# Showing a specific result within a loop

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, vba, loops

I'm trying to create a program which is able to encode using the RSA encrypt system. For this I've created code which is able to calculate using the [Euclidean Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm). Here's the code:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    number1 = TextBox1.Text
    number2 = TextBox2.Text
    Do While answer <> 0
        answer = number1 Mod number2
        number2 = number1 And answer = number2
    Loop
    MessageBox.Show(answer)
End Sub
```

So, that's nothing really difficult, right? The problem is that it will always show 0 as answer, which makes sense. But I want to have the answer of the loop before the last one.

Here is an [example]

[image]

if you don't understand what I'm trying to say.

I hope someone is able to help me :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not declare a variable to hold answer and check if it 0 before setting it?

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As                                                            System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
Dim number1
Dim number2
Dim answer
Dim whatIWant
    answer = -1
    number1 = TextBox1.Text
    number2 = TextBox2.Text
Do While answer <> 0    
    answer = number1 Mod number2
    number1 = number2
    number2 = answer        
    If answer <> 0 Then
        whatIWant = answer
    End If
Loop
MessageBox.Show (CStr(whatIWant))

End Sub
```

Here is a simple test you can do in Excel with the Messagebox showing 99 when done.

```
Sub TestIt()
Dim number1
Dim number2
Dim answer
Dim whatIWant
    answer = -1
    number1 = 148104 'TextBox1.Text
    number2 = 47223 'TextBox2.Text
Do While answer <> 0
    answer = number1 Mod number2
    number1 = number2
    number2 = answer

    If answer <> 0 Then
        whatIWant = answer
    End If
Loop
MsgBox (CStr(whatIWant))

End Sub
```

Comment: I've tried this, unfortunately it did not work. I've used "Dim whatIWant As Integer". But it still shows 0 as answer.

Comment: @KevinSebastian your logic is off.  I have updated my answer to correct the issue.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I must have interpreted your answer the wrong way, well, I'm not that experienced with VB.net either way. I've tried out your new code but it still shows 0. Besides that, I don't quite understand why there's a Dim prevAnswer as Integer when I don't see prevAnswer appear again, is there something I'm missing out there?

Comment: @KevinSebastian  prevAnswer was cause I copied the definition and didnt remove it for my example, it has been removed.  Try running the excel example.  My guess is that you didnt give answer an initial value so it defaults to 0

Answer (score 1):

```
    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As                                                            System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        dim prevAnswer as integer
        number1 = TextBox1.Text
        number2 = TextBox2.Text
        Do While answer <> 0
            prevAnswer = answer
            answer = number1 Mod number2
            number2 = number1 And answer = number2
        Loop
    MessageBox.Show(prevAnswer)
    End Sub
```

Comment: I've tried to implement this, but unfortunately it still gave me 0 as an answer, perhaps it has to do with the line prevAnswer = answer not being fully correct at it's place?

Comment: Not sure how prevAnswer is 0 when the condition is that answer can't be 0. Did you debug?

Comment: I don't understand it either, I indeed did debug and the messagebox gave me a 0 as answer.